# PHP writing to a text file on server

Tags: php, security

I have a log process that writes to a little custom .txt log file on my server when people supply input on a particular form (so I can keep an eye on those who are trying to use injection).

My question: This file is plaintext, and I do not link to it anywhere in my code other than the PHP calls `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`. Is there any way to see the file? Would a search engine possibly find it?

(I fully understand that this is security by obscurity. My question is how one might possibly "unobscure" this.)

Comment: well, are you writing the file to a place outside of the web root?

Comment: I believe it's in the web root

Comment: You can make a robots.txt file on your root with the appropriate line of code to remove that log file of yours of Search engines.

Comment: So anything I put in the webroot, no matter what, is public / linked on search engines?

Comment: Write it to a place outside of the web root, and put a login barrier on whatever script can read it. You can just use [`.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html) authentication

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would do that

Comment: inside the webroot isn't necessarily readable. You can restrict access to it. But it would be safer to store it outside of the webroot so that you server doesn't even have direct access to serve it up to the public

Comment: don't use some random folder name. That's still "security through obscurity". All it would take is server to have indexing turned off which could happen via any number of reasons and boom, your folder names are dumped to the user.  Make an effort to learn how to place the file outside of the webroot and call it from there. It's not that hard. Also make an effort to password protect the script that access the file (link above). It's not that hard either.

Comment: I don't think I understand what it means to be "outside the webroot." Apparently every example I have given is still in the webroot

Comment: @user3763670 The *webroot* or *document root* is the **filesystem** path that your web server uses as the root directory for your web site. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: If you didn't have a way to update `.htaccess` nor a way to write a file outside the document root, I would go for encryption =D

Comment: wht about using a db table instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I fully understand that this is security by obscurity. My question is
>   how one might possibly "unobscure" this.

They would need to be able to know your site’s code structure & logic. So if you name the directory the logs are stored in something other than `logs/` that is the first decent step. Or keep the directory named `logs/` but have it nested in another directory only you really know about such as `my_cool_stuff/logs`.

If you really want to be sure nobody get’s to it, you can always set an Apache config rule that would block anyone from directly reading `.txt` files directly from the browser, just use an Apache [`Files`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) directive like this in your web site’s Apache config or in an `.htaccess` on your site:

```
<Files ~ "\.(txt|yml|yaml)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

And as the official Apache documentation states about placement of `Files` directives:

> Note that unlike `<Directory>` and `<Location>` sections, `<Files>` sections
>   can be used inside `.htaccess` files. This allows users to control
>   access to their own files, at a file-by-file level.

So just place that in an `.htaccess` file on your server’s root and it basically tells Apache, *“Do not allow anyone to directly access files that end with a `.txt`, `.yml` or `.yaml` extension directly via the web server.”*

Now some people will recommend you simply place the file 100% outside of the main web root. And maybe this would help. But let’s say some malware infection gets into your code & someone can just browse your directory structure—which happens more than not—then it doesn’t matter what virtual rock you hide your data under: It will be exposed to someone who can penetrate your system & have the same access rights as the web user.

Or put simply: If Apache can access a directory & read a file, then if your site is penetrated, then the malware that penetrates will have the exact same access rights as Apache & thus can read files & directories pretty much anywhere Apache can.

That’s why I generally feel “security through reasonable obscurity” is the best real world tactic. Just block direct access to files you do not want parsed through the web browser, place those files in a reasonably obscure location—even if it is in the web root—and call it a day.

Comment: Where would I input that directive, exactly? (I'm a noob, excuse the ignorance)

Comment: I think maybe I am misunderstanding, isn't everything that branches from domain.com technically "connected to the webroot"? So domain.com/includes/ means includes is in the webroot? Or domain.com/whatever/ is in the webroot? What about domain.com/a/b? Would b be in the webroot?

Comment: Ok I tried putting that in .htacccess in the root folder, and now I get a Forbidden when I try to go to it directly. Awesome! And I can still write to it!

Comment: This is really exciting for me because I never knew you could block stuff this way

Comment: Going a bit deeper now.. is there a way someone could see my .htaccess file?

Comment: @user3763670 specifically, Apache has a similar `DENY` rule for `<Files ~ "^\.ht">` by default

Comment: Maybe I should make a new question for this but is there a way to block off access to entire folders (and their subfolders/files recursively)? Or blocking very specific files?

Answer (score 2):

To make it inaccessible from the web or search engines you would simply put that file out site of your web root directory. Be sure to have write permission on that folder :)

Comment: So if I put it in, say, includes/logfile.txt it'd be "safe"?

Comment: @user3763670 depends where `includes` is

Comment: Make sure it is outside of your root web directory. I think in Includes folder you may put CSS or JS files so that's accessible from anywhere.

Comment: @user3763670 in that case, then no

Comment: So the name of the folder matters, too? What about domain.com/flibbertyjibbets

Comment: @user3763670 *"outside the document root"* means **above** the document root. Say your docroot is `/home/user3763670/www`, something like `/home/user3763670/www-logs` would be inaccessible by HTTP.

Comment: So domain.com/some_unsafe_folder/some_safe_folder?

Comment: I feel like you are in a shared host environment and don't see anything above root. In that case you can use .htacess like other users pointed out if your hosting company allows you to do so.

Comment: if you are in a shared hosting env and don't have access above webroot or even ability to write to .htaccess and .htpasswd (server not setup to care about it) then I suggest you store your info in a db and pull the info from there and in your script wrap it in a condition that asks for a password

Comment: @Kalagan That's correct, I'm on a shared environment

Comment: @JakeGould It's basically the same as your answer though. All that can be done here is to deny access via HTTP. Whether by configuration or physical separation, the result is the same. The difference being that configuration can be changed externally; an admin could remove `.htaccess` execution for example